# Search ArrayList contain any other value apart from two mention values

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, arraylist

I have to search ArrayList whether is there any other value has been added apart from these two values:

Sample:
there are two values : `Test1 & Test2`
if arraylist Contain any other value apart from either of these two values. then it should return true.

what I have tried so far:

```
public static bool checkOtherValue(ArrayList arr)
{
    string[] vals = new string[5] { "Test3", "Test4", "Test5", "Test6", "Test7" };
    bool check = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if (arr.Contains(vals[i]))
        {
            check = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return check;
}
```

this will check with array and return if arraylist contain any of the mention string in string array. but I believe there should be shortest way of doing it.

such as `ArrayList.Find("Test1","Test2") == false;`

This function works for me:

```
public static bool ContainsAny(this ArrayList arr,params string[] values)
{
    bool check = false;
    if (arr.Count > 2)
    {
        check = false;
    }
    else
    {
        if (arr.Count > 1 && arr.Count <= 2)
        {
            if ((arr[0].ToString().ToLower().Trim() == values[0].ToLower().Trim() || arr[0].ToString().ToLower().Trim() == values[0].ToLower().Trim()) &&
               (arr[1].ToString().ToLower().Trim() == values[1].ToLower().Trim() || arr[1].ToString().ToLower().Trim() == values[1].ToLower().Trim()))
                check = true;
            else
                check = false;
        }
        else
        {
            //default value[0]
            if ((arr[0].ToString().ToLower().Trim() == values[0].ToLower().Trim() || arr[0].ToString().ToLower().Trim() == values[0].ToLower().Trim()))
                check = true;
            else
                check = false;
        }
    }

    return check;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write an extension method:

```
public static bool ContainsAny(this ArrayList arr, params string[] values)
{
     return arr.OfType<string>().Any(values.Contains);
}
```

And use it like this:

```
yourArrayList.ContainsAny("Test1","Test2");
```

But I would strongly suggest you to use type safe collections such as `List<T>` if you don't have to use `ArrayList`.

Comment: hello selman, this return true if Values are "Test1","Test3" but it should return false when there is any other value apart from Test1,Test2. please see my edit question.

Comment: @dawncode `return arr.OfType<string>().Except(values).Any()`

Answer (score 0):

> Sample: there are two values : Test1 & Test2 if arraylist Contain any
>   other value apart from either of these two values. then it should
>   return true.

If i'm correct this can be rephrased as: return true if not all of the values in the arraylist are in the test values.

If this is correct, the check can be simplified to:

```
public static bool ContainsAny(this ArrayList arr, params string[] values)
{
     return !arr.OfType<string>().All(values.Contains);
}
```